# regular expression to select particular word when it is not followed by particular pattern?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, awk

I have a list of the data in this format:

```
eth0: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0xfe<compat,link,site,host>
    loop  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0xfe<compat,link,site,host>
    loop  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I need to select `eth1` (which is the first word and it is a word which always starts with `e`) it is not followed by `127.0.0.1` (which could also appear later in the following line).

here `eth0` is not qualified because it is followed by `127.0.0.1`

I tried everything and nothing seems to work. is it even possible with a regular expression? if yes then how?

Comment: What's your expected output from above text and what's your platform?

Comment: I have a list of the above data, my expected output my look like `[eth0, eth1, eth2]` etc and the platform is Linux ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Ubuntu implementation details but you can make use of a negative lookahead:

```
^eth\d+(?=:)(?!.*\n.*[^0-9]127\.0\.0\.1[^0-9])
```

- `^eth\d+(?=:)` - the start of the line must be "eth", followed by one or more digits, and followed by a colon but do not capture the colon
- `(?!.*\n.*[^0-9]127\.0\.0\.1[^0-9])` - make sure that the contents which follow the previous match do not contain "127.0.0.1"

https://regex101.com/r/NeEAnn/1

Comment: @rahulKushwaha Try the new link, there was a typo in the previous data

Comment: can you please explain this to me?

Comment: I need an explanation of this `(?!.*\n.*127\.0\.0\.1)` i tried so maney thing to implement this like (?!.*127\.0\.0\.1.*) but failed! could you expand `(?!.*\n.*127\.0\.0\.1)`?

Comment: and why `(?!(.|\n)*127\.0\.0\.1(.|\n)*)` failed?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha Thanks, your comment made me think of an improvement to the regex. Check out the update.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha If you need a step-by-step syntax explanation then just hover your mouse over the regex at the regex101 link.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha NEVER use `(.|\n)*`, it is ALWAYS a wrong idea. `.` (usually) can match linebreaks provided the right option is passed with the regex pattern.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha I don't know why `(?!(.|\n)*127\.0\.0\.1(.|\n)*)` failed for you. It works at https://regex101.com/r/427amJ/1. You should consider providing a regex101 link whenever you have an issue. However, it is incredibly more costly to use that syntax.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha The reason that `(?!.*127\.0\.0\.1.*)` fails is because by default the period `.` does not capture newlines so I made sure to manually assert a newline with `\n`

Comment: `(?!(.|\n)*127\.0\.0\.1(.|\n)*)` this did work i was applying it incorrectly, like this `e[^ \t\n]*: ((?!((.|\n)*127\.0\.0\.1)(.|\n)*))`. It worked when i applied like this `e[^ \t\n]*: (?!(.|\n)*10\.106\.155\.208(.|\n)*)`. But exact reason of failure is not clear, Can you point out?

Comment: I expect that will work great on the regex101 web site since you seem to have tested it there but it won't work in any standard UNIX tool. I'm surprised the OP accepted it as the best answer.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha `\t` and `\n` matches a tab char and a newline char respectively. I recommend using the regex101 site to gain a basic understand of regex syntax.

Comment: @EdMorton The regex flavor and available toolset was unknown at the time of my answer which I addressed in my opening sentence. Users are encouraged to accept answers which helped them the most. OP is more than welcome to change the accepted answer if my answer did not help them achieve their goal.

Comment: Right, there's nothing at all wrong with your answer. As I said, I'm sure it'll work great on regex101, I'm just surprised the OP accepted it (and so effectively discouraged others from posting answers) given it won't work in any standard UNIX tool (lookaheads and `\d` are the problems) and from the comment they still seem to be struggling to get it to work using whatever tool they are using.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm really not sure. Based on their comments it looks like their tool does support lookaheads. Apparently I guessed correctly, I upvoted your answer though since it would be the right answer if OP is using `awk`.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's more likely, though, that their tool doesn't support lookaheads and is interpreting the lookahead syntax as something else (e.g. maybe `(` is being interpreted as the start of a capture group and `?` as zero-or-one repetitions, etc.) that just happens to not fail and produces the expected output for the one sample use case. But without knowing what tool the OP is using, we're all just guessing...

Comment: @EdMorton Beats me. If your `(?` theory is correct then I wonder how the subsequent `!`  isn't causing a failure.

Comment: idk, my best guess is the OP ran a different test against different input and is misinterpreting the results. Did you [notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009389/regular-expression-to-select-particular-word-when-it-is-not-followed-by-particul/60009579?noredirect=1#comment106130703_60009579) the OP changed IP addresses in the regexp they said works?

Comment: @EdMorton Inconsistencies between questions and comments occur in probably 95% of the posts I deal with so I've  learned long ago to not lose any sleep over it.

Comment: Actually I am executing command through the python and getting the output in python and apply regular expression! Initially, I wanted to use this in ubuntu shell only but the fact that I just could not write the regex in regex101.com irritated me so my focus shifted to just writing regular expression. actually I wanted to accept both the answer but StackOverflow doesn't allow, so I upvoted everything I could. please don't get me wrong, I don't want to discourage anyone

Comment: @rahulKushwaha no problem but FYI there is no such thing as "a regular expression": there are BREs, ERS, and PCREs. There are tools that use one of those by default, another with an argument, tools that read one line at a time, tools that read multi-line blocks given arguments, tools that support backreferences, tools that don't, tools that have specific delimiters that can't appear or must be escaped inside the regexp, tools with multiple regexp functions, tools with extensiuons to the POSIX ERE standards, etc., etc.

Comment: ... So never just ask for "a regular expression" as that could mean just about anything (and is often the wrong approach anyway - [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: @rahul oh okay, that makes sense. I had a feeling that you somehow had access to a PCRE implementation. Glad my solution worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` command which is natively available on Ununtu:

```
awk -F ': ' '$1 ~ /^e[[:alnum:]]+$/ && NF==2{s=$1; p=NR} 
       NR==p+1 && !/ 127\.0\.0\.1[[:blank:]]/{print s}'
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F ': '  # make ": " as input delimiter
$1 ~ /^e[[:alnum:]]+$/ && NF==2 { # if $1 starts with e and has 1+ alphanumeric characters later and there are exactly 2 fields in that line
   s=$1      # save $1 in var s
   p=NR      # save record no in var p
}
NR==p+1 && !/ 127\.0\.0\.1[[:blank:]]/ { # we are processing (p+1)th record and it doesn't have " 127.0.0.1 " in it
   print s   # print s
}
```

Comment: but the selected word should always start with `e` and after it may have numbers of letters than `:`.

Comment: ya! it's working. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: the `awk` command syntax is `awk options 'selection _criteria {action }'` but I am unable to find this structure in your code?

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F':' '!/[[:space:]]127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]/{print $1}' file
eth1
```

That will work using any POSIX awk in any shell on every UNIX box.